# Fiber bundle definition: Why is this a homeomorphism?

Tags: fiber-bundles

I'm getting started with fiber bundles and I have a doubt on the definition. I'll state just the part of the definition I'm in doubt: a fiber bundle is $(E,B,\pi,F,G)$ where $E,B,F$ are topological spaces, $G$ a topological group of homeomorphisms of $F$, $\pi : E\to B$ is a surjective continuous map and there is a open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $B$ such that

1. For each $U_i$ there's a homeomorphism $\varphi_{i} : \pi^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i\times F$ of the following form $\varphi_i(a) = (\pi(a), \psi_i(a))$. Let $x\in U_i$ we denote $\psi_i | \pi^{-1}(x)$ by $\psi_{i, x}$ and we can see that this is a homeomorphism between $\pi^{-1}(x)$ and $F$.

And then comes other conditions. Now, my doubt there is: how can we see that the mapping $\psi_{i, x}$ is a homeomoprhism? I know that $\psi_{i} = \pi_2 \circ \varphi_i$ where $\pi_2$ is the projection onto the second factor. Both $\varphi_i$ and $\pi_2$ are continuous and surjective, hence $\psi_i$ is continuous and surjective and so is it's restriction $\psi_{i, x}$.

Now, I was failing to see where injectivity comes from. I've tried like this: Let $\psi_{i, x}(a) = \psi_{i,x}(b)$, then we already know that $\psi_i(a)=\psi_i(b)$. Since both $a,b\in \pi^{-1}(x)$ we have that $\pi(a)=\pi(b)=x$ and so, this implies that $\varphi_i(a)=\varphi_i(b)$ and since $\varphi_i$ is homeomorphism this implies $a=b$.

Now the continuity of the inverse I can't see where it comes from. I've tried to show the inverse to be continuous, but I couldn't. How can I show this inverse is continuous?

Comment: Intuitively, $\psi_{i,x}$ is the restriction of $\phi_i$ to $\pi^{-1}(x)$. The first point $\pi(a) = x$ stays the same as you move around along the preimage over $x$. (Btw, your injectivity proof is perfectly fine.)

Comment: Hint: Use $p_2: U \times F \to F$, the projection into the second factor, and $i_x: F \to U\times F$, the inclusion of $F$ as $(x, F)$ in $U\times F$. Note that both of these maps are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

As a note, observe that this can be also be seen immediately by using the fact that [restrictions of homeomorphisms are homeomorphisms](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Restriction_of_Homeomorphism_is_Homeomorphism). Indeed in our case the subspace topologies in the domain and codomain are respected and $\left.\varphi_i\right|_{\pi^{-1}(x)}:\pi^{-1}(x)\to \{x\}\times F$ as we do all this over $B$.

---

Looking at the comments by Braindead, what I write above upgrades what he claims to be intuitive to rigorous, for all its worth.